# How is it possible that a 32bit application uses more than 5GB virtual memory?

Tags: windows, memory-management, 32-bit

I maintain a rather old 32bit application using largeadressaware that is deployed in an integrated system using always the same computer. Due to supply issues, the pc had to be changed and now the memory consumption is weird.
System details:

- Windows 10 OS
- pagefile is switched off for performance reasons
- 8GB RAM in old and new pc

After triggering a certain functionality which involves a pdf creation, the memory consumption tracked with performance monitor reaches more than 5GB. In addition, it does not fully recover from this peak, which it always did on the old pc.
All other functionalities seem to show pretty much the same memory consumption as before.

So my questions are:

1. How is it even possible that a 32bit application peaks over more than 5GB virtual memory consumption?
2. What can be reasons for this one functionality (and the libraries behind) to behave that differently on another pc?
3. Any ideas to solve this issue are welcome.

We checked the overall memory consumption of the application and did a lot of research on physical/virtual memory consumption. Especially for 32bit applications. I could not find anything covering that issue.